# Warnings by deploying ERC20 token sol,

Tags: deployment, solidity, erc20

I want to deploy my contract but I have so many warnings, I don't know every meaning.

> Gas requirement of function SpastToken.increaseApproval(address,uint256) high. (11 times in other functions)
>   BasicToken.balanceOf(address) : Variables have very similar names balance and balances. Note: Modifiers are currently not considered by this static analysis.
>
> Use assert(x) if you never ever want x to be false, not in any circumstance (apart from a bug in your code). Use require(x) if x can be false, due to e.g. invalid input or a failing external component.

```
contract Ownable {
address public owner;
event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed 
newOwner);

constructor() public {
owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
require(msg.sender == owner);
_;
}

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
require(newOwner != address(0));
emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
owner = newOwner;
}

}

contract ERC20Basic {
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
* @title ERC20 interface
*/
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns 
(uint256);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public 
returns (bool);
function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 
value);
}
/**
* @title Basic token
*/
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
using SafeMath for uint256;

mapping(address => uint256) balances;

uint256 totalSupply_;

function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
return totalSupply_;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
return true;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
return balances[_owner];
}
}

/**
* @title Standard ERC20 token
*/
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public 
returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
require(_value <= balances[_from]);
require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
return true;
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns 
(uint256) {
return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}
function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns 
(bool) {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender] 
[_spender].add(_addedValue);
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
return true;
}
function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public 
returns (bool) {
uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
} else {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
}
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
return true;
}

}

contract SpastToken is StandardToken, Ownable {

string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;
uint256 public initialSupply;

constructor() public {
name = 'SPAST-Coin';
symbol = 'SPAS';
decimals = 18;
initialSupply = 100000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals);
totalSupply_ = initialSupply;
balances[owner] = initialSupply;
emit Transfer(0x0, owner, initialSupply);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these warnings are pretty self explanatory. Except maybe the last one about the assertion. That one basically says that you should use `assert()` to check for logic errors in your code(that would be something you did wrong), whereas you should use `require()` to check if the inputs are legal or not(that would be the callers mistake). I don't think the rest of the warnings can be explained further, consider googling them. The one with the variable names however is just there to help you avoid typos from similar variable names and will not affect execution in any way. The modifiers warnings that do not appear here try to tell you that you could have stricter modifiers for your functions which again would make reading the code simpler.

Comment: this assert function  sholuld be replaced for require, but are this other warnings so bad that itwill destroy my smart contract or make it unsafe?

Comment: No, the variables and modifiers thing will not affect execution at all. The high gas warning is because you reference a dynamic array. So don't worry about that. If it passes the tests it is ok.

Comment: okay, but it affects the price of gas for sending erc20 tokens?
I tested the contract on testnet, i could deploy it  and have no problems.
But the gas price for sending are much high.

Comment: Some operations are more expensive so you cant always have low gas. Your transfer for example(since you talked about sending) cannot become any simpler without losing functionality. So the way you do things does affect the gas requirements for sending tokens, but you can only get it so low.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me =)

Comment: I replaced the assert function with require, but the warning, still exists, you know what it is about?
    Use assert(x) if you never ever want x to be false, not in any circumstance 
    (apart from a bug in your code). Use require(x) if x can be false, due to e.g. 
    invalid input or a failing external component.
    more

Comment: Not really sure about why it is still there. Could be just to help you remember it, since the compiler cannot really be sure about what you are using it for, but i am just guessing on this one, couldn't find anything specific. Also one more thing about the modifiers, it is possible to get an error due to modifiers if you use them wrong(e.g. change the state in a `pure` function) but this will be an error and not a warning so it will prevent you from compiling and deploying, and you will be able to fix it.